Using Kibana how can I visualize the cardinality of site visits by user
Say I have documents that includes a user ID and a timestamp that they visited my site.  I'd like to know how many users have visited the site x times.  I've been unable to find the right combination of aggregations to accomplish this.
Example Data:



User ID
Timestamp




A
12:30


A
13:50


B
11:10


B
12:11


B
10:20


C
15:00


C
19:00



I'd like to get an output that gives me data like:



Visits
Count




2
2


3
1



Ideally using a visualization in Kibana, but I'd settle for the results in an Elasticsearch query at this point.  I expect to have on the order of 100k unique users.
I've tried using a pipleline aggregation in Elasticsearch, but haven't been able to get it to show me the data in the way I'd expect.  And it would be limited to the number of unique values in my initial aggregation.
